# How do I redirect to a page based on form data?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, redirect

I've been doing research for about 2 days now but either it doesnt work or I don't know how the scripts work.

I have a HTML form with the `action` attribute posting to my email marketing service's url. The problem is, it is redirecting to the URL that I entered in the form settings on their side (`www.theirsite.com/myid/submissions/` is where `action` is POSTing to).

I want it to redirect to different URLs depending on which radio button is selected but I am only allowed to put in one URL for all submits.

Any help would be appreciated. I am new to coding but understand basic rules.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
Here is my form code.

`<form action="https://www.getdrip.com/forms/19579582/submissions" method="get" data-drip-embedded-form="19579582" data-drip-id="19579582">`

Radio buttons:

`<input name="fields[situation]" required="" type="radio" value="employed full time">
<input name="fields[situation]" required="" type="radio" value="employed part time">
<input name="fields[situation]" required="" type="radio" value="unemployed">
<input name="fields[situation]" required="" type="radio" value="retired">
<input name="fields[situation]" required="" type="radio" value="self employed">`

Button:

`<button type="submit" name="submit" data-drip-attribute="sign-up-button">My Button Text</button>`

Comment: We need code.  You post isn't clear.

Comment: Action toward a php file => In this php file, check your button radio. Depending on the value redirect toward the page you want.

Comment: You need to post some code if you want additional help.

Comment: Check out the FormData API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData . Prevent the default submit, send the data via AJAX and redirect from the client side based on the form values.

Comment: Cheers everyone will edit and clarify.

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is a fairly easy one to solve.

When a user selects a radiobox, you want the `<form action="www.theirsite.com/myid/submissions/">` to update.

Here is what you can do in plain JS:

```
<!-- So these inputs when clicked, will update your 'action' URL -->
<input name="myRadioButton" required="" type="radio" value="employed-full-time" data-marketing="employed full time" onclick="updateFormAction(this)">
<input name="myRadioButton" required="" type="radio" value="employed-part-time" data-marketing="employed part time" onclick="updateFormAction(this)">
<input name="myRadioButton" required="" type="radio" value="unemployed" data-marketing="unemployed" onclick="updateFormAction(this)">
<input name="myRadioButton" required="" type="radio" value="retired" data-marketing="retired" onclick="updateFormAction(this)">
<input name="myRadioButton" required="" type="radio" value="self-employed" data-marketing="self employed" onclick="updateFormAction(this)">

<!-- This is the bit that lets you decide what type it is -->
<input id="marketingValue" name="marketingValue" type="hidden" value="none" />

<script>
    function updateFormAction(radioButton) {
        // These 2 lines will update your forms ACTION URL
        // If there is only one form on the page this will work
        document.forms[0].action = radioButton.value

        // Otherwise select the form you want to target using ID
        document.getElementById('form-id').action = radioButton.value;

        // This will update your hidden input value
        document.getElementById('marketingValue').value = radioButton.getAttribute('data-marketing');
    }
</script>
```

That above code will do what you want. The `action = {value}` of the form will get updated each time a user clicks the radio button as it calls the `updateFormAction()` function.

Comment: Thanks I will try it! Is there a way to keep my `value` fields though? I need to keep them so that my email marketing service can track tags. Cheers

Comment: Sorry, which `value` field are you referring to ?

Comment: The radio button value. I have updated my question with some code if it sheds any light